# How to implement separate billing/shipping addresses and prevent use of PO Boxes?

Tags: 8, commerce

Because our products already have shipping included in the prices (using Commerce 2), we have no need for a separate shipping module or calculation. However, we do need separate billing and shipping address fields during the checkout process and a way to prevent PO Boxes from being used as the shipping address.

Why you might ask?  Because for some people living in rural areas or small communities, they often have a physical address that is recognized by UPS for packages, but have a PO box assigned by the US Postal Service for regular mail.  The Post Office will not deliver to their physical address and considers it an invalid address. So the PO Box will be used for billing to match their credit card, but we need to prevent that from also being used for their shipping address, as the client uses UPS exclusively.

How can this be implemented?  Both separate billing/shipping fields and excluding PO Boxes in the shipping address.

Comment: I really need some assistance / guidance here.  Anyone?